# How to free and release closed Chrome browsers related to chromedriver?

Tags: c#, process, selenium-chromedriver

I have a function in my C# application that performs a restart, and as part of this process, I need to close both the chrome process and the corresponding chromedriver process. However, I want to avoid forcefully terminating all my other normal Chrome browsers using commands like `TASKKILL /f /IM CHROME.EXE`, as this can lead to data loss and other issues.

I am currently using the following code to terminate the chromedriver and its associated chrome processes, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
foreach (var chromedriverProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver"))
{
    try
    {
        var chromeProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && p.Id == chromedriverProcess.Id);

        chromeProcess?.Kill();
        chromedriverProcess.Kill();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

but its not working im not sure what im doing wrong !

What was tried:

The code attempted to find all chromedriver processes and their corresponding chrome processes based on their IDs and MainWindowHandle. Then, it tried to terminate both processes using the Kill() method.

What was expected:

The expectation was that the code would successfully find the chrome processes associated with each chromedriver process and terminate them gracefully. This would result in the release of Chrome browsers that were opened by chromedriver.

I tried this approach did not work! get before process ids chrome and after

```
List<int> chromeProcessIdsAfter = new List<int>();
            foreach (var chromeProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            {
                chromeProcessIdsAfter.Add(chromeProcess.Id);
            }

static void restart_process(List<int> chromeProcessIdsBefore)
        {
            // Terminate all chromedriver processes
            foreach (var chromedriverProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver"))
            {
                try
                {
                    chromedriverProcess.Kill();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            
            List<int> chromeProcessIdsAfter = new List<int>();
            foreach (var chromeProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            {
                chromeProcessIdsAfter.Add(chromeProcess.Id);
            }

            // Find the process ID that is not in the "chromeProcessIdsBefore" list
            int seleniumChromeProcessId = chromeProcessIdsAfter.Except(chromeProcessIdsBefore).FirstOrDefault();

            // Terminate the specific Chrome process associated with your Selenium session
            if (seleniumChromeProcessId != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Process.GetProcessById(seleniumChromeProcessId)?.Kill();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```